# Cross results from thread to main

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a main thread with several progress bars. Each progress bar is the progress of a DataTable reading, so I have like 6 progress bar for 6 different variables `(DataTable dt1, ... dt2, ... dt3, ...)` and this is where the pain starts.

I have been using Task, Thread, BackgroundWorker, etc and I can't find a clean way to:

- Select the location of the information to read
- Load `Async` with Progress on the Main Thread
- Return the read `DataTable` and store it in the respective `dt`

I have done it with:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
        {
            dt1 = customProgress.Read<DataTable>("Path");
        }));
```

EDIT: My question was confusing, in fact. I will rewrite it:

Is there a more efficient way to cross this kind of information through the threads or a way to create a variable that stands "awaiting" for the result while the MainThread is running?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to execute code on a background thread, but you don't want to specify that the code should execute on a background thread?

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew()` is what puts that action on the thread pool so that it runs asynchronously and does not block main. If you remove that then it will block main() till it is finished. You could remove the `new Action()` because it knows how to cast a lambada appropriately but the rest is necessary if you want to run asynchronously.

Comment: Do you really think that's an excessive amount of code to accomplish such a complex task?  If this is a long and tedious amount of code for you, you're going to be in for some real doosies in your coding career.

Comment: Hi svick, all the code for the load is within Read<DataTable>("Path"), and he loads, but it takes time and it freezes the main UI, so I need to do it in a thread. However, the task is simple, but what I really want to know is if there is a way to pass async results over threads.

Comment: If the foreground thread waits for the background thread, the effect is that the UI freezes anyways.

Comment: @T.Castro It sounds like you're looking for the async/await model of programming that was added in C# 5.0.  Being on 4.0 you won't be able to use that.

Comment: Hi Servy, no, it is not a lot of code, it is minimal in fact. My core question here is if there is a way to cross results over threads or if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @T.Castro I advise you to remove or rewrite the last sentence of your question. From your last comment, I understand the Task is not working for you, like you want it to be?

Comment: Straight up BackGroudworker with reports progress will do this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx   I use it exactly this way.  And DataTable is slow - consider a List of a your-data-object

Comment: Servy, I just searched for the features in the C# 5.0 (.NET 4.5), 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/03/26/introduction-of-new-features-in-c-5-0.aspx
and its precisely that what I want. It seems I will need to stick with this until we adopt the new version. Thank you.

Comment: Would that not be the perfect case for using an Observer patern approach?

Answer (score 0):

No need to wait on main thread which will block UI. Instead you can setup a continuation when all tasks are finished using Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll() method. If you want to run this continuation on UI thread, then pass scheduler parameter as TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()